# SFML.Net can't locate native library on Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, native, sfml

I want to work with sfml.net. I succeeded and ran program in Windows, by copying dlls to output folder(both .net and csfml). I run Ubuntu 14.04 on second box, and have following error when running executable(with mono):

```
System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so.2.1
```

But :

```
ls /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-*
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.so
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.so.2.1
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.so
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.so.2.1
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.so
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.so.2.1
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.so
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.so.2.1
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so.2.1
```

Also I've tried to to add those with ldconfig

```
 sudo ldconfig -v | grep libcsfml
 libcsfml-system.so.2 -> libcsfml-system.so.2.1
 libcsfml-audio.so.2 -> libcsfml-audio.so.2.1
 libcsfml-network.so.2 -> libcsfml-network.so.2.1
 libcsfml-graphics.so.2 -> libcsfml-graphics.so.2.1
 libcsfml-window.so.2 -> libcsfml-window.so.2.1
```

No avail, and tried to add config file to project with dllmap, and when this not succeeded, added dllmaps to sfmlnet-window.dll.config, this is the file contents:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="csfml-window-2" target="/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so.2.1"/>
</configuration>
```

I'm lost here, what else can make it run?

ls -a: all libs user:user

Edit: ldd output:

```
/usr/local/lib/libcsfml2.1$ sudo ldd libcsfml-system.so.2.1
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4ebfe000)
libsfml-system.so.2 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb899904000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb8995fd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb8993e7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb899021000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb899e32000)
```

Comment: Your problem may be caused by insufficient access rights (please add output of `ls -la /usr/local/lib/` command) or missing native library dependencies (please add output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so.2.1` command).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have there user/user rwx privileges, so this shouldn't be a problem, but I'll should check dependency thing you've mentioned. I'll write this evening if it'll succeed.

Comment: Wait, looks like i found the missing link... libcsfml != libsfml

Comment: It seems you need to install [libsfml-system2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libsfml-system.so.2&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) package.

Comment: @jariq I figured it out, to work sfml .net needs csfml, which in its turn depends on sfml. Just missed one letter. Thanks!

Comment: I have added my original comment as the answer. Could you please accept it so I get some rep? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by insufficient access rights (please add output of ls -la /usr/local/lib/ command) or missing native library dependencies (please add output of ldd /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so.2.1 command).